# Changing SynthDef amplitude in realtime using OSC trigger/message and UGen

Tags: osc, supercollider

Sorry if this is very obvious, I'm very new to SuperCollider. I've followed a few suggestions from other threads but this application appears unique as I'm using OSC data from Max 8. I've run out of time so I'd hugely appreciate any suggestions.

I'm trying to change the amplitude of my Synth using [AmpCompA](https://doc.sccode.org/Classes/AmpCompA.html). I can change the frequency in realtime using OSC messages from Max 8, however, I can't apply AmpCompA in realtime using the same trigger/message. Is this possible another way?

Here is the code:

```
// setup synth
(
SynthDef.new("sine", {arg out = 0, freq = 200, amp = 1.0;
var sin;
    sin = SinOsc.ar(freq);
Out.ar(out, sin * amp);
}).send(s);
)

x = Synth.new("sine", [\freq, 200, \amp, 1.0]);

//test parameter setting
x.set(\freq, 400);
x.set(\amp, 0.1);
x.free;


//read from OSC message
(
f = { |msg|
    if(msg[0] != '/status.reply') {
        b = 1.0 * AmpCompA.kr(msg[1]);
        x.set(\freq, msg[1]); //this does work when I send an OSC message from Max 8
        x.set(\amp, b);  //this doesn't work? Can't set a control to UGen error
    }
};
thisProcess.addOSCRecvFunc(f);
)

s.sendMsg("/n_free", x);
```

[Max 8 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZOO2.png)

Error:

> ERROR: can't set a control to a UGen
> CALL STACK:
> Exception:reportError
> arg this = 
> Nil:handleError
> arg this = nil
> arg error = 
> Thread:handleError
> arg this = 
> arg error = 
> Object:throw
> arg this = 
> UGen:asControlInput
> arg this = 
> Object:asOSCArgEmbeddedArray
> arg this = 
> arg array = [*1]
> < FunctionDef in Method SequenceableCollection:asOSCArgArray >
> arg e = 
> ArrayedCollection:do
> arg this = [*2]
> arg function = 
> var i = 1
> SequenceableCollection:asOSCArgArray
> arg this = [*2]
> var array = [*1]
> Node:set
> arg this = 
> arg args = [*2]
> < FunctionDef in Method Collection:collectInPlace >
> arg item = 
> arg i = 1
> ArrayedCollection:do
> arg this = [*2]
> arg function = 
> var i = 1
> Collection:collectInPlace
> arg this = [*2]
> arg function = 
> FunctionList:value
> arg this = 
> arg args = [*4]
> var res = nil
> Main:recvOSCmessage
> arg this = 
> arg time = 626.8060463
> arg replyAddr = 
> arg recvPort = 57120
> arg msg = [*2]
> ^^ The preceding error dump is for ERROR: can't set a control to a UGen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the x.set to send numbers to a synthdef, but you can't use them to send functions or uGens. AmpCompA is a UGen - and therefore can only be used inside a synthdef.

You can modify your synthdef to use it:

```
(
SynthDef.new("sine", {arg out = 0, freq = 200, amp = 1.0;
var sin;
    sin = SinOsc.ar(freq);
Out.ar(out, sin * amp * AmpCompA.kr(freq));
}).send(s);
)
```

Your OSC message function only would ever send the frequency:
`x.set(\freq, msg[1]);`
The SynthDef uses the frequency to compute the psychoacoustic amplitude change.